# Can Client ID be Used to Retroactively Filter Internal Traffic?

Tags: google-analytics

With the goal of performing analysis that does not include staff traffic, I started following [this guide](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/simple-way-exclude-internal-visits-google-analytics/#commento-login-box-container) to exclude internal visits which seemed great but apparently cannot work retroactively. In fact, I've heard differing opinions on if any sort of retroactive filtering of this sort can be done in GA at all. I'm very new to using GA, but one field I noticed is the Client ID, which seems to track browsers. If I could identify which Client ID's correspond to my coworker's browsers, could I use this to retroactively exclude them from analysis? This seems like it may work to me, but I have found no sources online suggesting this as an option.

If it matters, the analysis I am most interested in is tracking exit clicks.

Answer (score 0):

ClientId is not a value normally available in Analytics reports, also if the coworker has deleted the cookies that value will be different.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for Univeral Analytics and not GA4.

With Google Tag Manager, you can create a configuration that allows you to filter out internal traffic.

In GA, you can create a custom dimension that tells GA which users are internal users and not. This information is passed on by Google Tag Manager via a query string.

For a step-by-step guide read: [How to Filter Internal Traffic in Google Analytics with Google Tag Manager](https://medium.com/lets-get-digital/how-to-filter-internal-traffic-in-google-analytics-with-google-tag-manager-2aadff50aad9)